# Python difflib.SequenceMatcher - wrong output (including with `autojunk=False`)

Tags: python, similarity, difflib

Most of the time, `difflib` does the right thing finding longest common sequence, but sometimes it is perplexingly inconsistent:

```
import difflib

a = 'department of pterfy hospital and jen manninger national institute for traumatology fiumei'
b = 'trauma center pterfy'
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b, autojunk = False).get_matching_blocks()

Out[230]: 
[Match(a=3, b=2, size=1),
 Match(a=6, b=4, size=1),
 Match(a=7, b=8, size=3),
 Match(a=13, b=13, size=7),
 Match(a=90, b=20, size=0)]

# no match on 'trauma', that is with b=0, size=6

# remove some characters from the front of a...
a1 = a[40:]
a1
Out[231]: 'nninger national institute for traumatology fiumei'

difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a1, b, autojunk = False).get_matching_blocks()
Out[232]: 
[Match(a=31, b=0, size=6),
 Match(a=37, b=10, size=1),
 Match(a=42, b=19, size=1),
 Match(a=50, b=20, size=0)]

# here is the match!
```

Similarly if we remove something from the end of `a` or `b`.

I understand, intuitively, longer strings are more difficult to handle, but the scale here is too small to affect anything. The underlying [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestalt_Pattern_Matching), as well as `difflib`, are quite mature, and this above doesn't look like a crazy edge case. (I'm aware of the [junk heuristic issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue2986), it should not be the cause here)

*UPDATE*

A straightforward implementation along the lines of [DP LCS algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Dynamic_programming) gives the correct result, so I conclude this behavior has to do with some undocumented "optimizations" in `difflib`.